# Gosmore Compile error on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: compilation, openstreetmap, mapnik

I want to compile Gosmore on ubuntu 11.10 server.

I got source code from :

http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/rendering/gosmore/

When i try command "make" command i got error like below:

```
gcc -lm density.c -o density
/tmp/ccNQSatu.o: In function `main':
density.c:(.text+0x21f): undefined reference to `exp'
density.c:(.text+0x224): undefined reference to `atan'
density.c:(.text+0x2c3): undefined reference to `exp'
density.c:(.text+0x2c8): undefined reference to `atan'
density.c:(.text+0x5d3): undefined reference to `exp'
density.c:(.text+0x5d8): undefined reference to `atan'
density.c:(.text+0x67a): undefined reference to `exp'
density.c:(.text+0x67f): undefined reference to `atan'
density.c:(.text+0x723): undefined reference to `exp'
density.c:(.text+0x728): undefined reference to `atan'
density.c:(.text+0x793): undefined reference to `exp'
density.c:(.text+0x798): undefined reference to `atan'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [jni/bboxes.c] Error 1
```

how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

exp, atan, these are in the math lib, it is called libm.a , you link to it with -lm which you did to, but in the wrong order : gcc -lm density.c -o density is wrong,  gcc  density.c -lm -o density is correct.

I am able to reproduce your problem with the latest version of gosmore, here is a patch in my copy of github.

https://github.com/h4ck3rm1k3/gosmore/commit/67bd8e2dd7e76de47a31b3c3df1ab33b8fda797b

dont forget a positive feedback! 
thanks
mike

Comment: Thanks Mike, i'll try it soon. :D